# The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any' on array reduce

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am getting on variable "v"

```
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
```

error in my following code.

```
const result = temp.map(o => {
            return Object.entries(o).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
                      v = v * 100;
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If you know the object will be something convertible to a number do `(+v) * 100`

Comment: What type is `o` and what are you trying to achieve in the end?